# How to input @TestTarget point when do provider verification?

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I am a new learner for pact and I want to know what should I input when do provider verification
for provider verification I should fill  provided target as localhost only or instead of localhost i also can input  actual env's host? which scenario is the best for contract test?

```
public class LoginProviderTest {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginProviderTest.class);


    @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget(?????);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Springboot, you can try like,

```
@TestTarget
public final Target target= new SpringBootHttpTarget();
```